# Dependency does not support framework .NETFramework, Version=v4.6

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-4.6, project.json

I am trying to get an MVC 6 web application up and running using the .NET 4.6 CLR, but I get the following kind of errors:

```
The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS 1.0.0-beta5 in project TestDeployProject does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.
```

**project.json:**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": { }
  },
}
```

[image: Reference issues .NET Framework 4.6]

According to this [blog post](http://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/), the .NET 4.6 target framework does work with ASP.NET 5.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike most `Microsoft.Framework.*` projects (like Caching for instance: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Abstractions/project.json#L7), `Microsoft.AspNet.*` packages only work with the "dnx-flavored" .NET Framework: if you want to use these packages in your own project, remove `net46` and add a new `dnx46` TFM and it should work.

Note that you'll need a recent DNX runtime version to use `dnx46`: don't hesitate to migrate to the latest nightly versions.